# PHP and mcrypt_decrypt(): warning about "initialization vector size"

Tags: php, cryptography, mcrypt

Why I get this warning message "Warning: mcrypt_decrypt(): Received initialization vector of size 44, but size 32 is required for this encryption mode in..." with this code?

```
$sessionKey = "Secr3t_Sess1on!Key_4t6ydv98*w8ds";
$data = "clear text";

$ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$keySize = mcrypt_get_key_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);


// Encode data
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$key = mb_substr (hash('sha256', $sessionKey), 0, $keySize);
$encryptedData = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
$encryptedB64Data = base64_encode($iv.$encryptedData);


// Decode data
$data = base64_decode($encryptedB64Data, true);
$key = mb_substr (hash('sha256', $sessionKey), 0, $keySize);
$iv = mb_substr ($data, 0, $ivSize);
$data = mb_substr ($data, $ivSize);
$data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
$decodedData =  rtrim($data, "\0");
```

Comment: do you see the difference between `$iv` in the encode section versus `$iv` in the decode section?

Comment: @castis Why is that the issue? The $iv of the decode section is extracted from $data (I read the first example http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)

Comment: Just as an FYI, [mcrypt is deprecated](http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt)

Comment: @Machavity I didn't know it. Which library do you recommend?

Comment: I would highly recommend using the [PHP OpenSSL library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php). OpenSSL is being actively developed.

Comment: @Machavity I'm sorry,  but I think that openssl is little documented. What should be with openssl the corresponding code of mcrypt?

Comment: Check out the first link I shared. He lists several PHP alternatives to mcrypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Problem is the mb_substr method.

```
$iv = mb_substr ($data, 0, $ivSize);
```

$data is treated as a multi byte string. That's why multiple chars are counted as one multi byte character. Just use the normal substr function should work.

Comment: One question: Why have I use substr (and not mb_substr), if I configured PHP to work in UTF8?

Comment: Because mb_substr can interpret the bytes in $data in a way that up to 4 bytes are counted as one UTF8 character. So it will not return the expected 32 bytes but 32 UTF8 characters which are then e.g. 35 bytes long.